# Slice a matrix in python using list of indices

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, slice

if I have a list of start and end indices for a given matrix in each dimension, is there any way to do slicing in an efficient way?
For example:

```
   a=10
   b=10
   x_0=np.zeros((5,a,b))
   i=[0, 5, 3, 5, 3]
   j=[2, 4, 0, 6, 6]
   x_1=x_0[:,i:i+3,j:j+3]
```

here x_1[k] would be (5,3,3). In the other words:

```
X_1[0,3,3]=x0[0,i[0]:i[0]+3,j[0]:j[0]+3]
X_1[1,3,3]=x0[1,i[1]:i[1]+3,j[1]:j[1]+3]
X_1[2,3,3]=x0[2,i[2]:i[2]+3,j[2]:j[2]+3]
X_1[3,3,3]=x0[3,i[3]:i[3]+3,j[3]:j[3]+3]
X_1[4,3,3]=x0[4,i[4]:i[4]+3,j[4]:j[4]+3]
```

or more genrally speaking:

```
for k in range(5):
   x_1[k]=x_0[k,i[k]:i[k]+3,j[k]:j[k]+3]
```

Any help wold be appreciated.

Comment: What about `x_1 = x_0[:,i[:3],:][:,:,j[:3]]`

Comment: How do you expect to slice an array of `0`s and end up with `(5,3,3)`?

Answer (score 1):

```
i = 0
j = 2
x_0[:,i:i+3,j:j+3]
```

produces a `(5,3,3)` array.

But what do you want to do with?

```
i=[0, 5, 3, 5, 3]
j=[2, 4, 0, 6, 6]
```

Do you want, for example, to produce a `(5,3,3)` array for each pair of values from `i` and `j`?

Or do you want to stack?

```
x_0[0,0:3,2:5]
x_0[1,5:8,4:7]
...
```

which could be produced with:

```
np.array([x0[kk,ii:ii+3,jj:jj+3] for kk,(ii,jj) in enumerate(zip(i,j))])
```

Here I collect 5 (3,3) arrays and join them into one.  It may be possible to join the indexes, and do the indexing once, but that will require some fiddling, and may not improve the speed.

Before worrying about doing things efficiently, lets be clear about what you want to do.  My guess is that you will need to iterate in one way or other over the values of `i` and `j`, and concatenate values.  It doesn't matter much whether you concatenate and then index or index and then concatenate.

---

If `x0=np.arange(500).reshape(5,10,10)`, the above expression produces:

```
array([[[  2,   3,   4],
        [ 12,  13,  14],
        [ 22,  23,  24]],

       [[154, 155, 156],
        [164, 165, 166],
        [174, 175, 176]],

       [[230, 231, 232],
        [240, 241, 242],
        [250, 251, 252]],

       [[356, 357, 358],
        [366, 367, 368],
        [376, 377, 378]],

       [[436, 437, 438],
        [446, 447, 448],
        [456, 457, 458]]])
```

Comment: Thanks for your comments. Yes, I want to create five (3,3) arrays. I'll update the question accordingly. Anyway, lets consider this example, you have couple large images( back above example, 5 images) and you want to pick a sub-window from each window with given start and end indices.